# Cross sections of Histogram3D in both dimensions

Tags: plotting, dynamic, histograms

I am trying to visualize a list of about 1 million `{x, y}` tuples, and for this I made

```
Histogram3D[data, {5},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, -100}, Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Count"},
 LabelingFunction -> Tooltip
]
```

[image: Histogram3D]

This is good enough to see a general trend, but now I'd like to pick a bin (say, $x \in [-5,0]$ or $y \in [50,55]$) and take a cross section from there to better understand how changing that one variable affects the distribution of the other.

What is a good way of doing this interactively? I tried controlling the plot range with `Manipulate[hist, {xrange, 0, 100, 5}]` but it's extremely slow and always aborts. I assume it's recalculating the  bin counts for the whole data set every time the value changes. It would also mean I have to edit the code if I want to see it from a bin on the $y$ axis which is not what I want.

Something like making all but the relevant bars transparent, or showing multiple discrete 2D histograms on a `Manipulate` window would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give up on displaying histograms as counts and use the "PDF" option as you're wanting to estimate a probability distribution.  Also, you should give up on histograms as there is an automatic way to obtain a "smooth histogram" which is generally what one expects the "true" distribution to be (*i.e.*, the underlying probability density function is many times expected to be relatively smooth).

Generate some data and produce a smooth estimate of the underlying distribution.  (I've only used 10,000 observations to speed things up.)

```
dist1 = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", 0.2}, {BetaDistribution[1, 3], BetaDistribution[3, 1]}];
dist2 = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", 0.2}, {BetaDistribution[6, 6], BetaDistribution[6, 6]}];
n = 10000;
SeedRandom[12345];
data = Join[RandomVariate[dist1, n/2], RandomVariate[dist2, n/2]];
data[[All, 1]] = -100 data[[All, 1]];
data[[All, 2]] = 100 data[[All, 2]];

SmoothHistogram3D[data, {Automatic, {"Bounded", {{-100, 0}, {0, 100}}, "Gaussian"}}, "PDF",
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Probability density"},
 PlotRange -> {{-100, 0}, {0, 100}, {0, Automatic}}, 
 RotationAction -> "Clip",
 SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ImagePadding -> {{100, 100}, {10, 10}}]
```

[image: Smooth 3D density plot]

You can produce estimates of the probability density conditional on a range of `y` values in the following manner:

```
Manipulate[
 x = Select[data, y - binWidth/2 <= #[[2]] < y + binWidth/2 &][[All, 1]];
 SmoothHistogram[x, {Automatic, {"Bounded", {-100, 0}, "Gaussian"}}, "PDF",
  PlotRange -> {{-100, 0}, {0, maxVerticalAxis}}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  MaxRecursion -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Probability density"}],
 {{y, 50}, 1, 99, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{binWidth, 5}, 2, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxVerticalAxis, 0.06}, 0.01, 0.20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate function of density slices]

**Addition:**

If you need speed for a demo, then constructing the conditional pdf's ahead of time will fix that.  Here's a limited example:

```
p = ConstantArray[0, 99];
Do[x = Select[data, y - 5/2 <= #[[2]] < y + 5/2 &][[All, 1]];
 p[[y]] = SmoothHistogram[x, {Automatic, {"Bounded", {-100, 0}, "Gaussian"}},
   "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-100, 0}, {0, 0.06}}, PlotPoints -> 200,
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Probability density"},
   PlotLabel -> ToString[NumberForm[Max[0, y - 2.5], 3]] <> " <= y <= " <> 
     ToString[NumberForm[Min[100, y + 2.5], 3]]],
 {y, 1, 99}]

Manipulate[p[[i]],
 {{i, 1, "y"}, 1, 99, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {i}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Manipulate of conditional pdf]

If you save the `Manipulate[...` line to a separate file, then the `SaveDefinitions -> True` option will store the individual images so you don't have to recreate those each time you open that file.

Comment: Great answer, but hey, while you're at it why not give the `Manipulate` a 2nd view - sections of the x axis as well?

Comment: Nice answer @JimB (+1)! It pains me when people use histograms in *Mathematica* or any other serious tools that offer much better PDF estimators. In my books, if somebody is using a histogram on a continuous variable, most likely,  they are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! To be fair I went for a discrete histogram and not for a KDE because I thought it would be much faster for something with `Dynamic`

Comment: "thought" ?  Did you try it?  The most time consuming part with a million observations is the selection of a subset of the data (2.2 seconds), followed by 0.24 seconds for the smooth histogram and 0.07 seconds for the discrete histogram.  The discrete histogram is 3 to 4 times faster than the smooth histogram but does that really make a difference?

Comment: If speed (because you probably want this as a nice demonstration to others) is what is important, then you can compute the smooth histograms ahead of time and make it lightning fast.

Comment: And removing the `MaxRecursion` option cuts the 0.24 seconds down to 0.1 seconds.

Comment: It is pretty much instant when I use your caching version of the code, both with smooth and discrete histograms. What I meant by the discrete histograms being faster was that before even seeing your code, I thought I could modify internal variables in `Histogram3D` and reuse that, instead of creating multiple histograms like you did.